# how to execute a git pull and ignore all changes

Tags: git

I need to constantly pull code from master to test.

when I execute some mvn commands files get overwritten, but i'm not commiting anything.

How do i execute the pull command and have it so i can just use the latest commits i've pulled.

Rebase does not seem to work.

Comment: A workflow where you're routinely throwing away local changes is asking for trouble down the line. It's almost certainly a better idea to change the structure of things in either your Maven tasks, your Git repository, or both, so that running your build doesn't overwrite files that are under version control. Having the checked-in copy of a file have a suffix like ".dist" or ".changeme" is a common way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

and then pull

```
git pull
```

You can read more in free git book - http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html

Comment: does not work, still getting the same issues. 'the following untracked tree files would be overwritten by checkout'

Comment: Try: git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD

Answer (score 2):

Are the files that are getting overwritten results of the build? Generally you shouldn't be committing compiled binary files to source control.

You may have to change how your project is set up a little bit, but you can use the .gitignore file to specify files or directories to not submit to git. You can either submit this file to git, which will make the ignore settings global, or keep it local to this continuous integration machine.

A basic .gitignore ([Source](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/19/ignoring-files.html)):

```
# Can ignore specific files
.DS_Store

# Use wildcards as well
*~
*.swp

# Can also ignore all directories and files in a directory.
tmp/**/*
```

Another, hackier option is to backup the files you're changing prior to the build, and restoring them upon completion of the build. That way you never have local changes out of sync with the branch.

Comment: +1. Ignore files that you don't want to version control. Don't "overwrite" them.

Answer (score 1):

You are tracking files that you are not supposed to be tracking. Don't :)

Patient: "Doctor, it really hurts when I do this."
Doctor: "Don't do that"